# Mac Big Sur don't recognize generic Wemos D1 MINI PRO based ESP-8266EX

Tags: esp8266

I bought one of theses cheaps & generic Wemos D1 MINI PRO with ESP-8266 to make a system to connect my lamp with google home etc.
But the problem is to upload the code into wemos. The Arduino IDE do not recognize the USB port that is connected.
[image]

When I connect to my Mac the board flashes the blue LED, so I suppose that it's not dead or something.
I've tried 5 different cables e nothing. I've read some articles about drivers to install but is only for [Sierra or High Sierra](https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver).
Also, uninstalled and installed the arduino IDE.
I installed the ESP8266 Boards in the Boards Manager.
I tested it out with an Arduino UNO board and it recognized normally.

I have no idea what to do. I don't have a windows PC in my house to test it out, as well.

Here the pics of the board:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are using a proper USB cable, charging cables don't have the data pair wires

Answer (score 1):

You need the CP210x drivers from [here](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers).

Comment: Just installed and didn't work. :( Rebooted the mac and checked for "systemextensionsctl list | grep -E '(silabs|cp210x)'" on terminal, it says that is activated enabled and the arduino IDE doesnt show the connected port.

Comment: @capanema, Do any new devices show up under /dev when it's plugged in?

Comment: @timemage yes, i have 1 arduino uno and 1 nano and both show up!

Comment: @capanema, so they show up under `/dev` but not in the `Tools/Port` menu?

Comment: @capanema Uno and Nano use a different interface chip. Does the D1 show up in /dev?

Comment: I'm wondering specifically what dev name is showing up.  In the past, at least, the IDE has been selective about what names it recognises as valid ports.